# windows 7 best screen capture (video maker) software?

Tags: windows-7, display, video-capture

I hope you guys using best screen capture s/w so you can suggest me and open source is almost welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Try [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/). It's free and open source.

> CamStudio is able to record all screen
>   and audio activity on your computer
>   and create industry-standard AVI video
>   files and using its built-in SWF
>   Producer can turn those AVIs into
>   lean, mean, bandwidth-friendly
>   Streaming Flash videos (SWFs).

Comment: hmm thts ma old collection camstudio since its opensource but video quality to poor anyway thnxs Mehper

Answer (score 3):

I use three different software packages for screen recording, depending on the specific task I'm trying to accomplish.

## [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)

Jing is free, but not open source. It lets you select either a specific window, an area of your screen, or the entire screen, and then records. It can also take still shots. You have the choice of uploading screenshots and screencasts to their free hosting service, to several popular services like YouTube or Flickr, and to your own FTP server. You can also just keep the files locally. Saves in swf format, the Pro version has an option for saving mpegs.

## [DebugMode Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/)

Wink is also free, but not open source. It's intuitive, and has more options than Jing, but because of those options takes more time to create a screencast. You can start/stop recording, join them together, add/remove frames, change the cursor in each frame, add notes/shapes/voiceovers. Outputs to swf format only.

## [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)

Simple, open source, records the entire screen or just a specific area, and outputs to AVI or SWF.

Comment: i tried Jing but its swf with its own flash player inside is it possible to avoid those player and only video and the clarity is good too

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that with their free version. With Jing Pro you can export to mpeg4 format, but the free version only does SWF. You might be able to find some application out there for extracting the video portion of it, you might try the firefox download helper addon perhaps. http://www.downloadhelper.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here that you can use. Only one is free though in this list:

- Camtasia Studios
- HyperCam
- Jing

Comment: nice i will try hypercam today JFW and i tried jing

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of video capture you are trying to perform.  If you are looking to capture video from within a game, give [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) a try.  You can record high framerate videos with FRAPS, and easily encode them to whatever filetype you need all in one interface.

If you are looking for an Open Source Screen capture program, try [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/).  It is very simple to use for the novice user, but also powerful enough for professional screen captures.

Comment: thanxs for your reply muncherelli :)

Comment: I've had some good experiences with Fraps for games, very simple to use tool.

Answer (score 0):

[InstantDemo](http://www.instant-demo.com/) is one which I use extensively.