# Need to capture full res screencasts from Android device for a commercial

Tags: display, android, screencasts

What I need is to record what is happening ON the android device and save it as a quicktime file. Similarly to the screencast in this reddit video: reddit.com/iphone (on the right, not the youtube video).

I'm not a software developer, but I have done enough reading online to get the Android SDK, Eclipse, and the necessary downloads to get it all working.

I am able to capture still screenshots using the DDMS, but I need to capture full motion video for an Android TV commercial.

So far I've called the manufacturer and several software guys, but haven't had any luck. I've even tried the HDMI out, but it's not pixel accurate, which is very important.

There has to be a way to do this, since the apps are featured in other commercials and videos, and I don't believe that the only way to do it is to film the device's screen.

No matter how complex the answer and solution to this might be, I'd love to find out. Even if it means bringing on someone to execute it.

I've found solutions that record at 5-6 fps, but I need it at 20-30 FPS.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Android emulator that comes with the SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)? If you can get your app running in the emulator on a PC, then you can use any normal PC video capture app to capture the video happening in the emulator.

See [How To Use The Android Emulator](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/12/15/android-emulator/)

There are quite a few questions on here about how to do screen captures on Windows, see a question like this: [Windows 7 best screen capture (video maker) software ?](https://superuser.com/questions/176692/windows-7-best-screen-capture-video-maker-software) for some ideas.